# How to load file in serverless.yml using variables?

Tags: serverless-framework

I want to load a file in sls.yml based on env.

Something like this:

```
"${file(src/data/resources_${opt:env}.yml)}"
```

However, this gives me:

> Error:
> Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
>
> - Cannot resolve variable at "resources.0": Value not found at "opt" source

How can I load a file based on a variable?

Comment: Could you share the full command that triggered this error? The usual way to distinguish specific environments is via `stage`